# Mac OS X annoyance: Waking up from sleep when I unplug my iPhone

Tags: macos, mac

When my Mac is suspended (sleep mode), and I unplug my iPhone, the computer always wakes up.  It's annoying because I didn't want to turn the computer on;  I simply wanted my iPhone.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: This is a pet annoyance of mine too - along with (as noted below) the way the machine wakes-up if you unplug a mouse/keyboard. I'd be very interested if anyone does have a fix/solution!

Comment: Anyone come up with a good work-around? In my case it's a catch-22 because I'm unplugging a wireless dongle that has my mouse and keyboard, so I can't tell it to sleep after it wakes up. A zombie, I guess. I hate shutting it down, but maybe that's my only choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so because the machine needs to run some routines to handle you unplugging the device.

EDIT: Let me explain a little more clearly :)

If you write an application that subscribes to mouse events, wouldn't you like to know if the mouse has vanished completely from the system? A more important example could be the OS X subsystem which detects when the user is inputting information so that it can awake from being asleep ... if the machine did not wake up when you unplug something it would never know that it is there again when you plug it back in, so if you unplugged a keyboard or mouse and plugged it back in, pressed a key or clicked the mouse, the system would not wake up again because it has not run the routines to handle it. I hope that makes sense to someone :)

Comment: Except it also happens to me when I unplug my mouse.

Comment: @dex: It's by design when you unplug or plug in an USB device it will wake up the computer.

Comment: Plugging/Unplugging USB devices while the machine is asleep is also a good way to crash it.  My powerbook will fail to wake up properly about 50% of the time when a device is removed while sleep mode is active.

Answer (score 3):

I don't buy that answer. If it need to know if a device has been disconnected or not, it could do this when it comes to a awake state.

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact is that you are changing the state of the USB Bus, and the computer *has* to process that.  On a PC, it's not as critical, because most manufacturers still want you  to use the PS/2 & mouse ports for keyboards....  So you don't normally have devices being plugged & unplugged on the USB bus...

Have you tried turning off automatic sync in itunes?  I believe that might resolve the issue...

Answer (score -1):

In Windows-PCs this is, so the computer can wakeup due to USB keyboard or mouse action.

I remember with PC there was an option in the BIOS to disable wakeup on USB - But I don't know if there is a similar option in Mac BIOS (hey, I don't even know if Apple even got a BIOS setup).